# Calculate CPU usage in percentage of Docker container with Docker SDK for Python

Tags: python, docker

I want to calculate the CPU usage in percentage of a running Docker container within a Python script. To get the docker stats I use the Docker SDK for Python version 5.0.0 . With the following code I retrieve the Docker container stats as dict:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()
container_list = client.containers.list()

for container in container_list:
    container_stats = container.stats(decode=True).__next__()
    print(container_stats)
```

I have found the formula to calculate the CPU usage in percentage (https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-calculate-the-cpu-usage-in-percent/27509/2). However, when retrieving the container stats  like shown above I am missing one variable. It doesn't contain precpu_stats.system_cpu_usage

My cpu_stats and precpu_stats are the following:

```
"cpu_stats":{
  "cpu_usage":{
     "total_usage":131226143110,
     "percpu_usage":[
        96196570,
        2133871570,
        349858200,
        32568251630,
        2009016800,
        13927275650,
        39496203460,
        40645469230
     ],
     "usage_in_kernelmode":5959000000,
     "usage_in_usermode":125246000000
  },
  "system_cpu_usage":16738784000000,
  "online_cpus":8,
  "throttling_data":{
     "periods":0,
     "throttled_periods":0,
     "throttled_time":0
  }
},
"precpu_stats":{
  "cpu_usage":{
     "total_usage":0,
     "usage_in_kernelmode":0,
     "usage_in_usermode":0
  },
  "throttling_data":{
     "periods":0,
     "throttled_periods":0,
     "throttled_time":0
  }
}
```

However, I need precpu_stats.system_cpu_usage to calculate the system_cpu_usage delta to be able to calculate the CPU usage in percentage.

Does anyone know why it doesn't show precpu_stats.system_cpu_usage, and maybe what I am doing wrong?

Comment: could you try using docker version 4.4.1, you could install it by `pip install docker==4.4.1`

Comment: Thanks for the hint of downgrading the Python package. However, still the same issue. `precpu_stats` doesn't contain `system_cpu_usage`.